# Jquery serialize function with file upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    contentType:'multipart/form-data',
    data: $('#regForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
```

its work perfectly but image and files will not be send by this. how can I resolve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload). The answer is that you can't upload files like this.

Comment: Take a look at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It might suite your needs for ajax uploading of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files directly with Ajax, but you can use an hidden iframe, and send form data using the `target="iframe_name"` attribute in `<form>`, see this tutorial: http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/upload-images

Comment: There's also the extended ability to handle files [available in newer browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)